# Better way to implement synchronous repeatable task using Spring/Spring-Batch

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, asynchronous, spring-batch

I have scenario when I need to poll database for specific result. I cant go on within my code until I get the expected result(except the case of passing the timeout interval)

Step A -> Steb B -> Step C

Simple way of doing this(but doesnt feel right for me) was:

```
numOfRetry=0;
invokeStepA();

while(true)
{
   numOfRetry++
   boolen result=invokeStepB();
   if(result || numOfRetry==3)
   {
      break;
   }
    else
   {
      Thread.sleep(100000)
    }
invokeStepC();
```

- Assume the database polling is occurring on Step B.

It doesnt feel right having this while loop on my Spring bean service while calling those jobs.

Maybe I could implement this better?

Thank you.

Farther explanation about my process:

Step A is Invoking external service to do some logic.

Step B need to poll another service which checking if Step A has finished it's work(In case it has finished I can proceed to StepC else I need to try again in X seconds and to check again)

StepC - another logic which must be accomplished only after StepB returned true.

- The logic which Step A is doing happens on external service.

Comment: http://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: But thats not just pre-scheduled task. I need to iterate on a blocking code synchronously and wait for an answer when it finish

Comment: In that case, it might be better to rethink your design so that you don't need that kind of synchronous behaviour. i.e. 'Step B' should run when 'Step A' has finished. 'Step A' **should not** instruct 'Step B' to start. That's the essence of batch flow definitions.

Comment: Step B start when Step A finish. But Step B is more "complicated" because it has to have inside some "blocking-scheduled logic". and when finish StepC should start. I wanted to make that "blocking-scheduled logic" smarter than having while loop and Thread sleep

Comment: I would use an event driven approach. Schedule the first job via cron or timer and the subsequent parts you use a simple event. (Just an idea thats why it's just a comment)

Comment: @Martin, could you pass any example?

Comment: @rayman, just added it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `asynchronous` way it happens like

```
int count = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(count);

invokeStepA();
for (int i = 0; i < RETRY_COUNT; i++) {
    Future f = threadPool.submit(new Callable() {
        @Override
        public Object call() {
            return invokeStepB();
        }
    }

    result = (YOUR_DATA_STRUCTURE) f.get();
    if (resultIsOK(result)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

However, I think since your task is ordered and assuming you cannot go to do something else, using `asynchronous` isn't really that effective. Please tell me more about your background in case you have special requirements.

EDIT: I think your new requirement looks like you need a proper way to tell if step A is finished fine. So you can use `CountDownLatch` to check if A has finished properly. I.e.

```
private final int count = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(count);

// invoke step A
invokeStepA();

// submit step B
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        invokeStepB();
        latch.countDown();
    }
});

// wait for step B
boolean result;
try {
    result = latch.await(TIME_OUT_IN_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECOND);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}

// Check result
if (result) {
    invokeStepC();
} else {
    LOG.error("Timeout waiting for step A.");
}
```

This assumes your `invokeStepA()` is a blocking method.

Comment: Sure. I edited my question plz check it out. thank you.

Comment: @rayman See if my edit is what you want. The count and thredPool is at class level and the rest is method level.

Comment: why do you write "step A is finished fine". I need to tell if step B finished fine. Step A invoking external service. step B invoking another external service that checking if stepA's service has finished. and when I get true I need to trigger Step C

Comment: @rayman Ah. Change the above stepA into stepB then. The concept is the same.

Comment: Thanks But I still dont understand where I check the result of StepB.. for example if true than continune to StepC else retry

Comment: I still didnt understand how you re-invoke the method after some time? I mean where is the re-try mechanism over here?

Comment: Oh. I didn't retry :) But you can easily add one.

Comment: How ? I mean how would you delay the re-try here? thats the whole thing I wanted to avoid Thread.sleep eh?

Comment: could you please modify your answer in a way that it has retry and wait interval btw each execution?

Comment: @rayman you don't need to retry since the `ContDownLatch` wound block on await() method and return either the result is ready or the TIME_OUT exhaust. Please read JDK documentation.

Comment: I understood how it works. Still not sure how you going to retry the mechanism? StepB should re-invoked until a success result received

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea by using an event driven approach. This is just out of my mind and not tested ;)

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;

@Service
public class JobA {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * ?")
  public void doStepA() {
    log.debug("some heavy lifting");
    Object someData = ....;
    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new JobAEvent("Jo, I'm finished", someData));
  }      

}
```

---

```
@Service
public class JobB implements ApplicationListener<JobAEvent> {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final JobAEvent event) {
    log.debug("do something more based on the event data"); 
    Object someMoreData = ....;
    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new JobBEvent("Dude, me too", event.getSomeData(), someMoreData));
  }

}
```

---

```
@Service
public class JobC implements ApplicationListener<JobBEvent> {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final JobBEvent event) {
    log.debug("do even more work");
  }

}
```

EDIT:
You can also call the method directly but then it runs synchronosly. Another possibilty is using '@Async'

Comment: when the  scheduler of  doStepA()  will start working? as soon as you call that method?

Comment: The one in my example runs every hour. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Comment: But again it's not good for me that it will run whenever. it's important that it will start to run as soon as I call this method and it should stop as soon as I get my expected result